# Hiding execution of exe from temp folder in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, exe

I am currently working on a project, I have developed a batch code that calls various other .vbs files and .HTA file as well.

I have used iexpress.exe tool built-in in windows to convert all these files to a single EXE that can run with ease on all computers in my environment.

The problem is running said EXE extracts all the batch and vbs files in temporary folder with the code in clear text for anyone to grab. Me being protective of my work, I would not like the code to be available for anyone to copy during execution from the temporary folder of any machine where that EXE is running.

Is there anyway or tool that can combine all the files into a single EXE and would run the EXE silently and invisibly (not in the temp folder).

I tried many tools out there but all seem to do the same behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No there isn't.

Comment: You can write an executable using, for example, C#. Anyhow anything you want to run on a user's machine, the user can intercept.

Comment: In addition to the advice you've already been provided, I doubt very much whether there is anything in your batch file you'd need to hide, all it is doing is running one or more other plain text file scripts, VBS and HTA. You would therefore also need to obfuscate or hide those files from being viewed too. The same issue will arise from doing that, at runtime, those would be extracted to their plain text version for execution too. Apart from that, I can almost guarantee that there is nothing about your code, which would need to be hidden, do you truly believe that you've created something new?

Comment: I never said I created something new, I am not getting my code patented. My point being here is that the code could be stolen and re-designed to fit a need in another environment. Me being protective of my work, I would like not to get my work used elsewhere without my permission.

Comment: What are the chances that you made something worth "stealing" that fits in a batch file? Consider that computer games, where hundreds of millions of dollars get invested to, get cracked as well. In your case, it's not worth the effort. The effort you're spending trying to not getting copied can be better spent adding value to your product.

Comment: Exactly my point @CodeCaster, who would want to steal a series of lines which run individual scripts either directly, using cscript.exe, or wscript.exe? Everyone knows how to run one or more executables one per line, they don't need to steal that, it's basic and common knowledge. The only reasons I can think of for trying to hide plain text commands is that they include sensitive information like passwords, or they're trying to perform malicious tasks. None of that really matters, however, because you've already been informaed that it cannot be done.

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster from making a good point.

Comment: @Compo You have a spelling mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible.

Batch is an interpreted language, which means that at some point, the script *must* end up in a state where `cmd.exe` can read and execute it. If it can be read by the interpreter, it can be read by the user. The only way to avoid having your source code read is to use a different language that can be compiled, like C.